# Understanding why a 450W power supply is destroying my ATX motherboards but not mATX

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

Maybe I'm missing something really obvious here, but after going through 3 new motherboards in trying to build my new machine, I'm finally certain that the 450W power supply I bought has been destroying them. It seems like it should be simple: just connect the connectors where they fit and switch the thing on. But today after hooking it to my ASUS Sabertooth 990FX TUF Series Motherboard and switching it on, I could see and smell the smoke coming out of the motherboard.

What I don't get is why I can hook this same 450W power supply up to my mATX motherboard and not run into the same problem. What am I missing here? Where on the box or manual is this?

(I have 8x2 GB RAM, AMD FX-4100 3.6GHz CPU, 1 512MB ATI graphics card, 1 WD 7200 RPM SATA hard drive. )

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#Interchanging_PSUs

Comment: Do the two motherboards use the exact same power connections?  Doesn't the ATX mobo require an 8-pin CPU-power cable versus only 4-pin cable for the microATX mobo?  Also, where are these mobos installed; are they in cases or on a workbench?

Comment: They both use same power connections and are in open cases.

Comment: Given that you use the same PSU connections, I'd say that the likelihood that the PSU is the problem is very, very low; there are other areas to suspect first.  As a general rule, the likely causes are probably: (1) a short due to metal object on mobo (I've seen this), (2) a short caused by the case, (3) motherboard fault (but with 3 failures seems less likely), (4) faulty adapter card, (5) everything else incl PSU.  Given the facts so far I'd put money on #2, the case is causing a short.  If you get another mobo, power it up on an insulated surface (e.g. the cardboard box in came in).

Comment: BTW as a rule you are better off assembling the motherboard outside the case, on a firm surface.  Otherwise be careful when pressing down to install components and connectors, and try to avoid flexing the motherboard.

Comment: @sawdust - I agree, Micros are 24 plus 4 power and the sabertooth is 24 plus 8. T Webster, what mAtx do you have? just curious.

Comment: I would have got a new PSU after mobo 2 started smoking.

Comment: @sawdust now on my 5th mobo, which happens to be a GIGABYTE mATX, but I don't think the mobo brand has anything to do with it. With a new 450W instead of 400W power supply and now a 6-core instead of 4-core CPU, it's running reliably. Not sure but the issue seems to be power related because I also now connect the machine to a new wall outlet and without going thru a surge strip. I'm just happy to finally put together a working machine and not have to resort to buying some overpriced, under-fitted box of bloatware.